# SQL Alchemy join not working

Tags: python, mysql, join, sqlalchemy

I have the following two tables

```
class Cities(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cities'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    city_code = Column(String(255))
    city = Column(String(255))
    state_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('states.id'))
    state = relationship("States")

class States(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'states'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    abr = Column(String(2), default='')
```

I am trying to perform a join on the tables to replace the state_id in the Cities table with the name and abr of the state and have all this data in a single object.
I have tried all the following things but get "nope" all 4 times.

```
    from models.city_data import Cities as CitiesTable
    from models.states import States as StatesTable

    result = db.session.query(CitiesTable).join(StatesTable, CitiesTable.state_id==StatesTable.id).first()
    try:
        print result.name
    except:
        print "nope"

    result = db.session.query(CitiesTable).join(StatesTable).first()
    try:
        print result.name
    except:
        print "nope"

    result = db.session.query(CitiesTable).join(CitiesTable.state).first()
    try:
        print result.name
    except:
        print "nope"

    result = db.session.query(CitiesTable).join("state").first()
    try:
        print result.name
    except:
        print "nope"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Nothing seems to work.
Or am I understanding joins incorrectly?

I want something like the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM cities JOIN states ON cities.state_id=states.id;
```

Comment: What is `CitiesTable`?

Comment: sorry fixed code, i imported it as CitiesTable for other reasons

Comment: Well, `Cities` objects don't have a `name` attribute, so of course you can't do `result.name`. What you probably want is `result.state.name`.

Comment: but is there a way to combine these and actually join them? I want something like: SELECT * FROM cities JOIN states ON cities.state_id=states.id;

Comment: If you want to do the join explicitly, use [`contains_eager`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager); otherwise, do `db.session.query(CitiesTable).options(joinedload(CitiesTable.state))`.

Comment: i tried the joinedload, but i still cannot do result.name

Comment: Use `joinedload`, then `result.state.name`.

Comment: is there any way I would be able to do result.name? I just want to have everything in one object

Comment: If you want to keep using the ORM, you can use [association proxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html); if you're fine using SQLAlchemy Core, then you can do `result = db.session.execute(select([CitiesTable.__table__, StatesTable.__table__]).select_from(CitiesTable.__table__.join(StatesTable.__table__, CitiesTable.__table__.c.state_id == StatesTable.__table__.c.id)))` then `result["name"]`.